# Cannot cUrl self with public IP

Tags: centos, networking, firewall

My home network has a CentOS based server connected to it. I have a router, where the 80 and 443 ports are forwarded to that server.

I can reach this server with the public IP of the router and everything works as intended. I can also reach this server with the public IP from inside the network.

The problem arises when I want to reach the server from within the server with the public IP.

so when I write `curl xx.xx.xx.xx` in the cli of any computer, other than the server itself, I get a response. But when I write that same command on the server, I get no response. I took a look with Wireshark, but all I saw was `[SYN]` packets are sent to the public IP without response.

What can cause such problems?

I use `firewalld` on the server and the ports are open. I also set it up to log denied packets, but I didn't see anything blocked related to these requests.

If I write `ping xx.xx.xx.xx`, it works everywhere, even on the server. `traceroute` finds the route to the server from everywhere. It's probably not the ISP blocking the packet, because that would mean that I either couldn't reach the server from out, or from within the network.

EDIT: I have a Xiaomi AX3600 router

Comment: Is the server even allowed to go out at the router? If so will it be NATed to the same public IP it is visible as from outside or perhaps a different IP generally used for outbound connections?

Answer (score 0):

Some home routers do not handle a request from *inside* the router to its *outward* facing IP address.  I had this issue with some Linksys and Netgear routers back in the day.  I imagine if you `curl` the host's LAN IP, it will work as expected.

Comment: yes, it does. But then why can it handle requests from other computers within the network to the public IP?

Comment: That is a question for the manufacturer of the router in question.